# How to add item to Adobe Flash context menu?

Tags: javascript, flash, contextmenu

Is there any way I can add an item to the context menu using JavaScript and HTML? I will use Flash if necessary.

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage), but the solution was to create your own context menu. 
I just want to add an item to it, like seen in [this Flash game](http://armorgames.com/play/6561/achievement-unlocked-2). Is this only possible with Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood you need to add items to flashplayer context menu, and it is possible with `actionscript`:

```
var cMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var item1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("some text");
cMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
cMenu.customItems.push(item1);
contextMenu=cMenu;

item1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, func1);

function func1(e:ContextMenuEvent):void{
    //do some thing when item1 clicked
}
```

find more in [this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3contextmenu/).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add buttons to a browser default context menu is developing an extension for the browser.

So you need your custom context menu which can be done using HTML elements (+JavaScript), or Flash. Of course Flash Player is installed on most browsers nowadays; but there's a very low possibility that your website viewer doesn't have Flash Player installed on his browser.

Therefore, I suggest you to create your context menu using **HTML + CSS + JavaScript** *(jQuery will help a lot)*. For examples, you may want to take a look at [MediaFire](http://mediafire.com), [Yahoo! Mail](http://mail.yahoo.com), etc.

Comment: If you looked at the Flash game I showed, you would see that it just _added_ an item, not creating a new menu.

Comment: @Ptr13: This Flash game has added an item to its own menu! Not the browser context menu!

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but it's a high up hit in google for this topic, so I'm linking an answer from a similar thread in SO. The question from the link is greasemonkey specific, but the answer contains javascript and jquery code that will answer *this* question using *this* answer's methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017187/userscript-add-item-to-right-click-menu/24145259#24145259