# :contains() does not return the expected nodes

Tags: jquery, replace, greasemonkey

Please, consider the following code:

```
// @include     /(^https?:\/\/www\.|^https?:\/\/)google\.com(\.|\/).*/
// @include     /(^https?:\/\/www\.|^https?:\/\/)stackoverflow\.com\/.*/
// @include     /(^https?:\/\/www\.|^https?:\/\/)userscripts-mirror\.org\/.*/
// @include     http://wiki.greasespot.net/*
// @version     1.0
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle


$ ( 'body:contains("serscripts.org")').each ( function ()  {

var results = $(this);
var text = results.text();
console.log(text);
text = text.replace( /serscripts\.org/ig, "serscripts-mirror.org" );
text = text.replace( /(:8080|%3A8080)/ig, "");
    //results.text ( text );

} );
```

I expected the return should be just the elements containing that string, but the result on the console is all the text of the body.

---

Consider [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017187/userscript-add-item-to-right-click-menu/24145259#24145259) at line:

```
// @updateURL       https://userscripts.org/scripts/so...
```

I want to change that.

---

Or [this one](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Scope_Runner) :

```
// @require http://userscripts.org/scripts/source...
```

I'd like to change too.

---

All words between tags should be checked for the string, and return only the ones that have it.

What is the right selector for this?

---

**Note**:
Link attributes and text between `<a></a>` are already changed using a similar `.each ( function )`.

Comment: You selected **`<body>` elements** containing `serscripts.org` somewhere inside them. You got exactly that.

Comment: You might want to add a space before that semicolon

Comment: take `body` out of selector

Comment: @DJDavid98 I didn't get it, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:contains` is returning exactly what is expected. From [the spec](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

> The matching text can appear directly within the **selected element**, in any of that **element's descendants**, or **a combination** thereof.

---

In general, to replace, wrap or highlight text terms on a web page, you need to work at the individual `TEXT_NODE` level.  Anything else risks trashing: URL's, id's, event handler's, etc.

You can use a [Tree Walker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker) for this:

```
var txtWalker   = document.createTreeWalker (
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    {   acceptNode: function (node) {
            //-- Skip whitespace-only nodes
            if (node.nodeValue.trim() )
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;

            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        }
    },
    false
);
var txtNode     = null;

while (txtNode  = txtWalker.nextNode () ) {
    var oldTxt  = txtNode.nodeValue;
    var newTxt  = oldTxt.replace (/serscripts\.org/ig, "serscripts-mirror.org");
    newTxt      = newTxt.replace (/(:8080|%3A8080)/ig, "");

    txtNode.nodeValue = newTxt;
}
```

this will safely take care of everything on the page, except for HTML attributes like `href`, `src`, etc.

If you wish to change those, use separate, targeted `.each ()` code -- like you said you were doing -- but do not change the text between `<a></a>` as that will already have been done by the tree walker.

Comment: Thank you Brock, that worked fine. I removed the "between tags" handler