# Greasemonkey simple html text replacing not working

Tags: html, text, replace, greasemonkey

I need to replace all the olds links of an HTML page by the new web page so I created the following script

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace('www.forumoldpage','www.forumnewpage');
```

Save it but when I open the web page do nothing.

There's something wrong with the code or do I forgot something to do?

Comment: Are you having this run after the page loads?

Comment: I have two Firefox windows, one normal and one private; on the private I have the page previously loaded. When I add the script to Greasemonkey and activate it for *newpage* then reload the web page. I tried also on the normal Firefox window, same result, nothing. With nothing I means that I see the page without format as I saw it before activate the script.

Comment: I think we need more details to help, does it has any errors on console? As far I understood your question, I think this answer is gonna help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613081/contains-does-not-return-the-expected-nodes

Comment: More details like what? I want to search one string and replace it for another.  I used the code from above and nothing happen; so I wonder if I do something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was led to this question when trying to create my very first greasemonkey script, so I thought it's for the benefit of everybody if this question has an answer.  Try this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('www.forumoldpage','www.forumnewpage');
```

`replace` gives you a new string with the replacement effected, but you still have to replace the contents of the web page.