# Tampermonkey - Right click menu

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

With Tampermonkey is there any way to create a right click menu option in Chrome?

I found `GM_registerMenuCommand` but it does not seem to show any new items in the right click menu.

Another problem is I use `GM_openInTab` in the test script but it seems to loop infinitely for some reason. It should only trigger after the menu is clicked, why would this happen?

Also I am wondering is there a way to do this in a more advanced way with custom right click icons etc?

There was a GM script for Firefox that worked for menus but in Chrome nothing seems to show so it would be good to have a way to have this working.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Context Menu
// @namespace       http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description     Test
// @version         0.1
// @author          author
// @include         *
// @exclude         file://*
// @grant           GM_openInTab
// @grant           GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==]


(function() {
    'use strict';

function test() {
    GM_openInTab("https://website.net");
}

GM_registerMenuCommand("hello", test(), "h");

})();
```

Comment: Use [@run-at context-menu](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=1170)

Comment: @wOxxOm do you have a simple code example of how this would work? That thread seems to be someone requesting a feature.

Comment: I didn't try it myself but I can tell you one thing: the feature is implemented.

Comment: you are calling test() within the registerMenuCommand function, instead of passing it as a function. try doing `GM_registerMenuCommand("hello", test, "h");`

Answer (score 20):

As per [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800590/tampermonkey-right-click-menu#comment72728401_42800590) comment, it is possible using [`@run-at context-menu`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at).

**Example**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Go to Website.Net
// @namespace       http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description     Context menu to execute UserScript
// @version         0.1
// @author          author
// @include         *
// @grant           GM_openInTab
// @run-at          context-menu
// ==/UserScript==]


(function() {
    'use strict';
    GM_openInTab("https://website.net");
})();
```

**Result**: (works nicely :)

<kbd>[image: Userscript shown at context menu]</kbd>

Comment: Nice one; I had not known about `@run-at context-menu`.  (Foolishly using Greasemonkey as my primary engine (pre GM 4))

Comment: Yes, me too, learned from the comment and went to check. Quite handy for single-actions :)

Comment: Sadly this is Chrome only: https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:run_at

Comment: @DanielKaplan `@run-at context-menu` works fine on Firefox 121.0

Comment: @Fonic hm, the documentation still says, `The script will be injected if it is clicked at the browser context menu (desktop Chrome-based browsers only).` Is it out of date? Maybe I'm misinterpreting it.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Either the documentation is outdated or Mozilla applied some change to Firefox that makes this possible and the Tampermonkey authors haven't noticed yet.

Comment: @Fonic Good to know. [Perhaps you could submit an issue to their github repo?](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues) In my experience, they are very responsive and usually respond within a few hours.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Good idea, done -> https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/1960

Answer (score 13):

Instead of `GM_registerMenuCommand("hello", test(), "h")` you should have `GM_registerMenuCommand("hello", test, "h")`

The first version calls the `test` function immediately, and then passes its result to `GM_registerMenuCommand` function. The second passes the function itself instead of its result.